# Writing Output of the subprocess into text file

Tags: python-2.7

I wanna write out put of the process which will be run using subprocess into test file. Below is my code.

```
Proc = "./server.sh >>out.txt"
Subprocess.Popen(proc,stdout=subprocess.Pipe,shell= True)
```

If I run above code , only first three lines of out put is written, can any tell how to get my process entire output into text file?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a file handle directly to the `Popen()` constructor:

```
    with open('/tmp/out.txt', 'w') as tempf:
        subprocess.Popen('server.sh', stdout=tempf, shell=True)
```